# Const vs. Static in a switch statement

Tags: c#, pass-by-reference

I'm converting some old VB.NET to C#. Among the more minor issues I've come across is how to handle passing large objects into methods. In VB we would use the ByRef keyword, like this:

```
    Friend Sub New(ByRef Parent As WorkSheet)
        'INITIALIZE OBJECT
        Me.WS = Parent
        pColorId = 64
        pZoomScale = 100
    End Sub
```

But in C# there are a long list of limitations that make this not possible. For instance, refs cannot have default values, you cannot pass in a constant, null or `this` because those are read-only.

Is there a simple solution to this? Or do you just ignore it and pass everything without a qualifier and the compiler just does the right thing?

Comment: please show the body.

Comment: It's about 600 lines. Is there something in particular that's needed?

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz Do you actually know what `ByRef` means? You only need to pass something `ByRef` if you want to assign it a value that is also visible outside the function.

Comment: Maybe show how those parameters are used

Comment: you don't need to pass the objects as `ref`, all classes are reference types and don't need to be passed by `ref`

Comment: @Reza Aghaei thank you, I thought that was the case.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz You are welcome:) I posted this as answer to be more useful for future readers:)

Comment: Where did that title come from?  There's nothing about Static or Const anywhere in your question or code.

Comment: @Ben Voigt, seems like it was copied from an earlier question that Chrome autofilled into the field. Never noticed it!

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz you can edit the question title to be more meaningful and also can kindly accept the answer to be more useful for other readers in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to pass objects by ref, all classes are reference types and don't need to be passed by ref in your case.

> [Passing Reference Type Variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s6938f28.aspx)
>
> A variable of a reference type does not contain its data directly; it
>   contains a reference to its data. When you pass a reference-type
>   parameter by value, it is possible to change the data pointed to by
>   the reference, such as the value of a class member.

---

> Do not confuse the concept of passing by reference with the concept of
>   reference types. The two concepts are not the same. A method parameter
>   can be modified by ref regardless of whether it is a value type or a
>   reference type. There is no boxing of a value type when it is passed
>   by reference.

Answer (score 0):

In C#, all references to classes that derive from `object` are copied to the method. When you pass an object reference to a method, you operate on the actual object passed in.

The `ref` keyword that you refer to is a reference to a reference, and you only need to use that if you plan to change the reference itself that is passed in (in your example, you'd need `ref` if you planned to set `Parent` to null, and wanted this to apply outside of the method).